# How to fix uuid error in buildFromSessionId(uuid)?

Tags: java, android, diagflow

I'm trying to get diagflow running on android. But I can't get past buildFromSessionId(java.lang.String) in AIServiceContextBuilder cannot be applied to (Java.util.UUID). What have I done wrong? I am totally missing something.

```
import java.util.UUID;
import ai.api.AIServiceContext;
import ai.api.AIServiceContextBuilder;
import ai.api.android.AIConfiguration;
import ai.api.android.AIDataService;
import ai.api.model.AIRequest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    UUID uuid;
    AIDataService aiDataService;
    AIServiceContext customAIServiceContext;
    AIRequest aiRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void initChatbot(){
        final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("<Client Access Token>",
                AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
                AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
        aiDataService = new AIDataService(this, config);
        customAIServiceContext = AIServiceContextBuilder.buildFromSessionId(uuid);
        aiRequest = new AIRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: The buildFromSessionId method requires a String as a parameter. A UUID is a completely different class. Try `AIServiceContextBuilder.buildFromSessionId(uuid.toString())`